# Undefined String for Mongoose.connect() on deploy, but works locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to deploy a node app to Render, but keep getting this error message: **MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.**

After searching on here for a while and trying different things, I'm still getting the same result and I don't really know why. My connection works locally, but when I try to deploy it fails.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/.env'});
const cors = require('cors')

const quizRoutes = require('./router/quiz');
const articleRoutes = require('./router/article');

const app = express(); 

//middleware
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
    });


app.use('/quiz', quizRoutes);
app.use('/articles', articleRoutes);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
            console.log(process.env)
            console.log('Port', process.env.PORT);
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

```
PORT=4000
MONGO_URI="mongodb+srv://personalinfo.lahdouv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Changed Mongo_URI for obvious reasons, but that is the code I'm working with.

I tried changing the .env config, putting the URI in quotes, and trying to make sure that the .env file was being linked correctly. Locally, I used console.log to make sure, and it still works. Not sure where to go from here.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Where do you save the `mongo_uri`, in `.env` or `.env.production`?

Comment: It's in the .env which is in the root folder of the project. I tried adding an image, but says I can't yet.

Comment: You can upload to `imgur`, if possible. So is the .env file existing on the server? Where did you deploy the app?

Comment: I deployed it on Render. I just double checked to make sure that the env file was there, but I don't think it was. Just made sure to add it and change the environment variable and that made it work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using env file you can try this. There is an extended option in render to add environment variable before the apps starts to be deployed . select advanced option and you will see an option to add environment variable . add variable save and deploy

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just tried this along with double checking the server and that helped! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because of the format You have used in .env file to store the uri,
You have written something like this

```
PORT=4000
MONGO_URI="mongodb+srv://personalinfo.lahdouv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

But in .env file if you will store the uri without quotes and white spaces like this , this error will most probably eliminated (worked for me also).

```
PORT=4000
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://personalinfo.lahdouv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```